# Can you get an internal IP for an Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

We're currently working on some proof of concept type stuff with Azure. We have a virtual network configured to which we've deployed some test Cloud Services (basically basic Web Roles created in VS2013).

Ideally we'd like to be able to make calls within our virtual network to these Cloud Services using internal IP addresses (we do intend to have our own DNS solution in place) but only seem to be able to get the internal addresses for the instances running within the Cloud Service and not the Cloud Service itself (for which we can only get the public VIP address). Obviously making any calls to the instances directly means we lose out on the load balancing/scaling that Cloud Services offers for a Role deployment.

Can anyone tell me if finding out the internal IP address is even possible, or are we trying to do something that quite simply can't be done/is inadvisable?

Comment: I have cloud service with VMs deployed in it, and I can see cloud service's public virtual IP by looking at cloud service dashboard, and both public virtual IP and internal IP by looking at virtual machine dashboard. I believe you should use the public virtual IP and not internal IP. That way load balancing and service scaling works as intended and there is no extra trouble for you to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks Sopuli. Would having to communicate with your own services like this count as public traffic though in terms of billing?  I had also seen a couple of articles for internal load balancers but this seems to apply to a VM deployment scenario rather than the Cloud Service scenario.

Comment: Good question. I have to admit I have no idea. The service I'm running is so small I haven't paid any attention to that.